# Error when trying to run U-SQL script locally

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I've implemented a U-SQL script which uses a custom extractor. The custom extractor is implemented in a separate class library (For U-SQL Application), which is called from the U-SQL script's code-behind file. When I try to run the job locally, I get this error:

> E_RUNTIME_USER_LOADENGINEASSEMBLY: .Net cannot load runtime assembly 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll'.
>   Description:
>   A procedure imported by 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll' could not be loaded.
>   Resolution:
>   Ensure the file exists and that all dependencies are available, including ScopeEngine.dll. 
>   This runtime assembly requires a 64-bit process and depends upon the VC14 CRT runtime being installed on the local machine.

I get a similar error when I try to register the extractor assembly locally:

> [Job Error]
>   E_RUNTIME_USER_LOADENGINEASSEMBLY: .Net cannot load runtime assembly 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll'.
>   Description:
>   A procedure imported by 'ScopeEngineManaged.dll' could not be loaded.
>   Resolution:
>   Ensure the file exists and that all dependencies are available, including ScopeEngine.dll. 
>   This runtime assembly requires a 64-bit process and depends upon the VC14 CRT runtime being installed on the local machine.
>   ==========  Local execution failure ==========

Comment: Which OS are you using?  There was an error introduced recently for Windows 7 where you have to install the Windows 10 runtime given in the link.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Where can I find the link to the Windows 10 runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7 a recent update to Azure Data Lake Tools has introduced a dependency on the Windows 10 runtime.  Consider either upgrading  your OS (Windows 7 is getting on bit), or download the runtime from the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234

I believe this URL is supplied in the error message.  Download and install the correct version for your OS and machine.

Follow the instructions here which worked for me:

https://github.com/Azure/usql/issues/66

Comment: I have Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, but when I tried to install the Win10RT, it said "Update for Windows (KB2999226) is already installed on this computer". Is there any other way to get Azure Data Lake Tools to work on Win7?

Comment: Hmm, what version of the tools are you using?  The current one is 2.2.6000.1 available from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504).

Comment: That's the version I'm using.

Comment: That made it work! I think it was the downgrading of the U-SQL SDK that made it. Thanks!

Comment: Painful eh, I'm upgrading to Win 10 soon anyway.